# Font issue with TM symbol in SSRS reports

Tags: sql, reporting-services, fonts

I have the following code that works correctly, but I need to adjust the font properly.

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!new_trademarkname.Value),"",Fields!new_trademarkname.Value & ChrW(8482))
```

The issue is if I use my font "Architecht's Daughter", the ™ symbol does not appear as superscript (small.)  If I use Bookman or other ordinary font, this is ok.

Is there a way to rework the formula to have ChrW(8482)) coded with a seperate font? Like the following:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!new_trademarkname.Value),"",Fields!new_trademarkname.Value & <font = "arial"> ChrW(8482))
'''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another placeholder in the **same textbox** for your superscript and adjust the font in the toolbox/properties (F4) window:

placeholder1 with your font "Architecht's Daughter":

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!new_trademarkname.Value),"",Fields!new_trademarkname.Value)
```

placeholder2 with a regular font:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!new_trademarkname.Value),"",ChrW(8482))
```